# Tab's content overlaps its neighbour's tab's content

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Let me explain the issue with the help of the following example:

> I added 3 tabs e.g. TAB1 , TAB2 and TAB3. Now If I delete TAB2, the
>   remaining tabs will be TAB1 and TAB2 (as TAB3 will take TAB2 place
>   now). Now, when I add a new tab e.g. TAB3, I will see 2 tab's contents
>   at the same time. One which tab was newly created and second which tab
>   was right behind the newly created tab.

I monitored the HTML at the time of addition and deletion of the tab by inspecting and also checked array's index values they were changing fine.

As far I could detect, the cause of it is that the content tab of the newly added tab is actually getting static "active" class which does not changes.
I guess ui.bootstrap is the causing this issue.

I'm using the following code to make tabs functionality I need.
**HTML code is:**

```
<uib-tabset active="activeForm">
    <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in $scope.tabs" heading="{{tab.title}} {{$index+1}} " active="{{tab.active}}">
        {{tab.content}}
        <button type="button" class="btn pull-left btn-primary" ng-click="removeTab($index);">
            Delete this wave
        </button>
    </uib-tab>
    <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="addNewTab();">
        +
    </button>
</uib-tabset>
```

**And js code is:**

```
$scope.tabs = [
    { title:'TAB'+($scope.tabs.length+1), content:'This wave of contacts will be activated before all other waves of contacts.', active:true }
];
$scope.addNewTab = function() {
    $scope.tabs.push(
    {
        title:'TAB'+($scope.tabs.length+1), content:'Content for tab new tab.'
    });
    $scope.removeTab = function(index) {
        if($scope.tabs.length>1) {
            $scope.tabs.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
}
```

*One more thing, I'm totally new to both AngularJS and angular ui.bootstrap. So, please treat me as a beginner.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use "track by $index" in ng-repeat if you are using $index in your logic (html)

e.g ng-repeat="tab in $scope.tabs track by $index"

Comment: You rock brother. Now I get it what I was missing. Thanks alot :)